# How to set writing direction in Tesseract OCR?

Tags: ios, tesseract

I am trying to set writing direction in Tesseract for Arabic, Urdu and other languages for my iOS application.When I tried to set like this

```
G8RecognitionOperation *tesseract;
tesseract.tesseract.writingDirection = G8WritingDirectionRightToLeft;
```

It gives error "Assignment read only property". Please answer with correct code. 
https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/blob/master/TesseractOCR/G8Constants.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

writingDirection property is read only and will be detected when recognized text.

G8WritingDirection in G8Constants.h are the possible writing directions.

I tried to recognize this image :

[image: sample image]

with the following code:

```
G8RecognitionOperation *operation = [[G8RecognitionOperation alloc] initWithLanguage:@"ara"];
operation.tesseract.language = @"ara";
operation.tesseract.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ara.png"] g8_blackAndWhite];
operation.recognitionCompleteBlock = ^(G8Tesseract *recognizedTesseract) {
    NSLog(@"recognizedText=%@", [recognizedTesseract recognizedText]);
    NSLog(@"writingDirection=%lu", (unsigned long) recognizedTesseract.writingDirection);
};
```

And I got the output as:

```
recognizedText=شكر ا جزيلا
writingDirection=1
```

Comment: But in this, you are not setting the writing direction but you are just logging. But I think line "operation.tesseract.language = @"ara";" will help me as in my code this line is missing and I am not recognizing the text as it always read from Left to Right. I am reading from camera output, not from image. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I receive this error "tessdata_manager.SeekToStart(TESSDATA_INTTEMP):Error:Assert failed:in file adaptmatch.cpp, line 511
" while recognozing arabic language. I am not using "G8OCREngineModeTesseractOnly" but still error remains same.

Comment: From Github, gali8 / Tesseract-OCR-iOS, issue #209:  
Arabic language work only in G8OCREngineModeCubeOnly.

I have changed initWithLanguage in G8Tesseract.mm as below:

- (instancetype)initWithLanguage:(NSString*)language
{
    if ([language isEqualToString:@"ara"])
        return [self initWithLanguage:language configDictionary:nil configFileNames:nil cachesRelatedDataPath:nil engineMode:G8OCREngineModeCubeOnly];
    else
        return [self initWithLanguage:language configDictionary:nil configFileNames:nil cachesRelatedDataPath:nil engineMode:G8OCREngineModeTesseractOnly];
}

Comment: I am doing same:  recOperation.tesseract.language = srcInitCode;
recOperation.tesseract.engineMode = G8OCREngineModeCubeOnly; where "srcInitCode" = @"ara" and recOperation is "G8RecognitionOperation" but still getting error. What are other parameters you are using?